# Tableau missing dates with value 0

Tags: date, null, tableau-api, missing-data

I want to build a line graph, and I have missing dates in my data. I would like to get value 0 for the missing dates.

With the option `'Show Missing values'`, all dates are shown in the graph. But the missing dates do not have any values but they appear and the line passes over them.

Values for missing dates are not real NULLs. And therefore, I can not use functions like `IFNULL` or `ZN` to transform NULL values to 0, because it is not a real NULL. Do you know how to solve the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean you have `null` as a string in place of missing dates?

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated field for measures in your graph:

```
IF [Dates]=NULL THEN 0 ELSE [Measure]
```

Use this calculated field instead the original measure.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below calculated field and then click on **date** field pill and choose the option **"show missing values"**

*ZN(SUM([Amount])) * (IIF(INDEX()>0 ,1, 1))*